# Convert VMware ACE VM to normal

Tags: vmware-workstation

Is it possible to convert a VMware ACE virtual machine to one usable in the normal VMware Player or Workstation? Does this depend on the installed OS of the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible usingthe vmware-acetool, using the cloneToVM method. There are a couple of caveats to doing so though:

1. The VM has to have the administrative tools policy on it
2. You must have the recover key enabled if your using authentication

See more details [here](http://www.mxcad.com/VMware/Using-the-vmware-acetool-Command-Line-Tool.html).